# Android - Custom textview which support text selection and underline

Tags: android-custom-view, clickable, underline, textselection, spannable

I want to make custom view or textview, which supports text selection and can also underline part of text string on long press and move-after-long-press events(drag to next line to underline) with different colors of underline. Undelined text can be clickable and get underlined text. I had tried to draw string in canvas and use SpannableString, UnderlineSpan and Clickable Span to draw underline and selection, But failed to get result as required.

Please help! Thank you in advance.